# Removing line-height causes text to appear outside of text-boxes

Tags: html, css

Question 1: Why does removing line-height in the inner div cause the text to remove itself from inside of it?

Question 2: How can I get the text to also align at the bottom of the small boxes? Do I need a third div to accomplish this?

```css
#parent {
  line-height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: solid black 1px;
  padding: 20px;
  
  
}

#parent div {
  
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 40px; /* Removing this line causes text to move outside of div */
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: solid black 1px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div>
  A
  </div>
  <div>
  B
  </div>
  <div>
  C
  </div>
  <div>
  D
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Removing the line height on the inner divs causes those to inherit the line height from the parent div, thus making them also 200px. Try `line-height: initial;`

Comment: Wow, thanks! I was not aware of the `initial` value. It could have saved me some time the other day when I was working with font-sizes. :)